# How to add checkboxes with select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to add checkboxes to my current select_tag options. I have only been able to add one checkbox, instead of multiple checkboxes. And the one checkbox that I do get to appear will throw off the entire format of the drop down menu. I only want a small checkbox for each option.

`= select_tag :ethnicity, options_for_select(['Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other']), prompt: 'Ethnicity'`

[image]

Here's end result when adding check_box_tag:

[image]

Comment: Checkboxes and select tags are two very different things that are not intended to be combined. Why do you want this? is there another way of solving this without mashing together two incompatible html objects? (eg a dropdown menu that doesn't use a select-tag at all, just divs with checkboxes in it?)

Comment: Have you looked at Bootstrap Multiselect? https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the `<select>` tag is used for picking one option, however, there is an attribute that allows selection of multiple options.

`<select multiple="multiple">`

One caveat: You must hold shift on a PC or command on a Mac, which from a design perspective isn't great UX.